# Javascript - change image and text on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im very new to javascript and still very much learning. I'm trying to change the text and image in a div based on a users selection from a dropdown.
I can get the image to change or the text to change but can not get both to change. If  someone can point me in the right direction and tell me where am I going wrong in my code, it would be greatly appreciated. Code follows:

**Javascript**

```
function swapImage(){
    var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
    var dropd = document.getElementById("swapImg");
    image.src = dropd.value;    


    var model = document.getElementById("model");
    var heading = document.getElementById("heading3");
    var textGrey = document.getElementById("textGrey");
    var textGrey2 = document.getElementById("textGrey2");

    if(dropd.value == "images/1.jpg"){

        model.innerHTML = "A4";
        heading.innerHTML="This text matches A4 model";
        textGrey.innerHTML="kjhkjh we ewf kjikjkj we";
        textGrey2.innerHTML="hf efjkj efe  edeeeeejm dff";
        return false;
    }

    else if (dropd.value == "images/2.jpg"){
        model.innerHTML = "A6";
        heading.innerHTML ="This text matches A6 model"; 
        textGrey.innerHTML ="xxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxx";
        textGrey2.innerHTML="yy yyyy yyyy yy";
        return false;
    }

    else if (dropd.value =="images/3.jpg"){
        model.innerHTML = "A8";
        heading.innerHTML ="This text matches the A8 model"; 
        textGrey.innerHTML ="zzzz zzzzz";
        textGrey2.innerHTML="pppp ppp pp p p";
        return false;
    }
}
```

**HTML - div to change text and image**

```
 <div id="carbox">
   <h2 id="model" class="model">A6
<img id="imageToSwap" src="images/3.jpg" width="544" height="203" style="margin-left:275px; margin-top:-82px" />
</h2>

    <div id="carbox-bottom">
    <h3 id="heading3" class="heading3">Loren ipsum dolor sit ame</h3>
    <p id="textGrey" class="textGrey">Coisteahi fwior he qvbsi dolo wetiuyy thuoi loren ipsum dolar </p>
    <p id="textGrey2" class="textGrey2">Coisteahi fwior he qvbsi dolo</p> 
    </div>  
    </div>
    <!--End carbox-->
```

**Dropdown**

```
<select id="swapImg" name="model" class="modelSelect" onchange="swapImage()" >
   <option value="images/1.jpg">A4</option>
<option value="images/2.jpg" selected="selected">A6</option>
<option value="images/3.jpg">A8</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your

```
 <h2 id="model" class="model">A6
<img id="imageToSwap" src="images/3.jpg" width="544" height="203" style="margin-left:275px; margin-top:-82px" />
</h2>
```

The `<img>` is **INSIDE** the `<h2>`. So when you change the innerHTML of your `<h2>`:

```
var model = document.getElementById("model");
model.innerHTML = "A4";
```

You lose the `<img>`.

Fix: have the `<h2>` end earlier:

```
<h2 id="model" class="model">A6</h2>
<img id="imageToSwap" src="images/3.jpg" width="544" height="203" style="margin-left:275px; margin-top:-82px" />
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cMXd5/1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [HTML5 data attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) to assign multiple values to any elements.

Use data attribute to assign "heading, description, image url" to each select options (in your case) and access those values `onChange` event of `dropdown` list from `javascript`.

**HTML**

```
<select id="swapImg" name="model" class="modelSelect" onchange="swapImage()" >
   <option value="images/1.jpg" data-model="A4" data-heading="Model A4 heading" data-description="Model A4 description">A4</option>
   <option value="images/2.jpg" data-model="A6" data-heading="Model A6 heading" data-description="Model A6 description" selected="selected">A6</option>
   <option value="images/3.jpg" data-model="A8" data-heading="Model A8 heading" data-description="Model A8 description">A8</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    function swapImage(){
    var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
    var dropd = document.getElementById("swapImg");
    image.src = dropd.value;   

    //getting selected option
    var option= dropd.options[dropd.selectedIndex];
    //getting dataset of option (defined with data attributes)
    var data=option.dataset;

    //accessing data attribute values
    console.log(data.model);
    console.log(data.heading);
    console.log(data.description);


    var model = document.getElementById("model");
    var heading = document.getElementById("heading3");
    var textGrey = document.getElementById("textGrey");

    model.innedHTML=data.model;
    heading.innedHTML=data.heading;
    textGrey.innedHTML=data.description;

}
</script>
```

Demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLGFc/)

Reference:

1. [About HTML5 data-attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)
2. [Accessing data-attribute in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)
3. [using jQuery to work with data-attribute (very easy)](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer ill give it a try and let you know

Comment: this will be my 1st time working with HTML5 so ive got a bit of reading to do, the image is changing but the text is NOT changing. Do I need to add code somewhere, am I missing something? Thank you  for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try using FireBug to debug your code. Using Chrome or Mozilla press F12 - this will show you the fire bug window, and you can debug your code.