# Change text and image/video on click and scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, react-redux

I'm just a novice. I know some html, but I have no idea how to do the following:
there is an html page, it has a section or div with 3 columns (1st column - text, 2nd - video, in the 3rd column there are 4 links).

When the user scrolls to this section, I need the page to stop (I would like to but not necessarily), and while the person scrolls, it should change the text in the 1st column and the video in the 2nd(both same time) . And also the user should be able to scroll through these videos&text by clicking on the links in the 3rd column. How it is done here: [fleet-app](https://fleet.postmates.com/fleet-app/)

It's written in React, so I can't to spy the solution.

I found this solution [Javascript - change image and text on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648515/javascript-change-image-and-text-on-select), but I can't figure out how to apply it in my situation.

Is it possible to do this with Javascript or CSS or something else?

Please don't scold me too much - I'm just learning:)

The solution I got now is very ugly - example codepen.io/Avelaskes/pen/rNOKVbQ

```js
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {  

        // Scroll to Top
        jQuery('.scrolltotop').click(function(){
            jQuery('html').animate({'scrollTop' : '0px'}, 400);
            return false;
        });
        
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
            var upto = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            if(upto > 500) {
                jQuery('.scrolltotop').fadeIn();
            } else {
                jQuery('.scrolltotop').fadeOut();
            }
        });


        
         var forEach=function(t,o,r){if("[object Object]"===Object.prototype.toString.call(t))for(var c in t)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t,c)&&o.call(r,t[c],c,t);else for(var e=0,l=t.length;l>e;e++)o.call(r,t[e],e,t)};
            var hamburgers = document.querySelectorAll(".hamburger");
            if (hamburgers.length > 0) {
              forEach(hamburgers, function(hamburger) {
                hamburger.addEventListener("click", function() {
                  this.classList.toggle("is-active");
                }, false);
              });
            }   
        

        
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
                var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
                // Show/Hide Tabs
                // Show/Hide Tabs
            jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).siblings().slideUp(400);
            jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).delay(400).slideDown(400);             
                // Change/remove current tab to active
                jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        }); 
        
        
        
    });
})(jQuery);(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {  

        // Scroll to Top
        jQuery('.scrolltotop').click(function(){
            jQuery('html').animate({'scrollTop' : '0px'}, 400);
            return false;
        });
        
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
            var upto = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            if(upto > 500) {
                jQuery('.scrolltotop').fadeIn();
            } else {
                jQuery('.scrolltotop').fadeOut();
            }
        });


        
         var forEach=function(t,o,r){if("[object Object]"===Object.prototype.toString.call(t))for(var c in t)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t,c)&&o.call(r,t[c],c,t);else for(var e=0,l=t.length;l>e;e++)o.call(r,t[e],e,t)};
            var hamburgers = document.querySelectorAll(".hamburger");
            if (hamburgers.length > 0) {
              forEach(hamburgers, function(hamburger) {
                hamburger.addEventListener("click", function() {
                  this.classList.toggle("is-active");
                }, false);
              });
            }   
        

        
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
                var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
                // Show/Hide Tabs
                // Show/Hide Tabs
            jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).siblings().slideUp(400);
            jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).delay(400).slideDown(400);             
                // Change/remove current tab to active
                jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        }); 
        
        
        
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800&family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');

body {  
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;    
      background: #fff;
      color: #333333;   
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

::selection {
    color: white; 
    background: #C840E9;
}

::-webkit-selection {
    color: white; 
    background: #C840E9;
}

::-moz-selection {
    color: white; 
    background: #C840E9;
}

.scrolltotop {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    background: #5773FF;   
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 8px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    display: none;
    transition: 0.2s all ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s all ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s all ease;
}

.scrolltotop:hover {   
    background: #C840E9;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);   
}

/*---- header-area start ----*/
.header-area {
    background-color: #15161C;
    padding: 25px 0;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.2s all ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s all ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s all ease;
}

.navbar-brand img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.main-menu-part ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.main-menu-part ul li {
    float: left;
}

.main-menu-part ul li a {
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 52px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.3s all ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

.main-menu-part ul li a:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.hamburger {
  padding: 10px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-property: opacity, filter;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-transform: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible; 
  outline: 0px!important;
}

.hamburger:hover {
    opacity: 0.7; 
}

.hamburger-box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; 
}

.hamburger-inner {
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px; 
}

.hamburger-inner, .hamburger-inner::before, .hamburger-inner::after {
    width: 40px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #13F1FC;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease; 
}

.hamburger-inner::before, .hamburger-inner::after {
    content: "";
    display: block; 
}

.hamburger-inner::before {
    top: -10px; 
}

.hamburger-inner::after {
    bottom: -10px; 
}

.hamburger--squeeze .hamburger-inner {
  transition-duration: 0.075s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.hamburger--squeeze .hamburger-inner::before {
    transition: top 0.075s 0.12s ease, opacity 0.075s ease;
}

.hamburger--squeeze .hamburger-inner::after {
    transition: bottom 0.075s 0.12s ease, transform 0.075s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.hamburger--squeeze.is-active .hamburger-inner {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition-delay: 0.12s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}

.hamburger--squeeze.is-active .hamburger-inner::before {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: top 0.075s ease, opacity 0.075s 0.12s ease; 
}

.hamburger--squeeze.is-active .hamburger-inner::after {
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transition: bottom 0.075s ease, transform 0.075s 0.12s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1); 
}

/*---- rkma-area start ----*/
.rkma-area {
    background-color: #15161c;
}


.mnrkma_top {
    background: url(img/bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 60px 0;
    padding-bottom: 545px;
}

.rkma_top h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.rkma_top p {
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
    color: #B7E6FF;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.rkma_part {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation:animation-hci0jy 5s 2s infinite alternate;
    animation:animation-hci0jy 5s 2s infinite alternate;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.43,0.05,0.6,0.99);
    animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.43,0.05,0.6,0.99);
}

.rkma_part img {
    width: 334px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;

}

.rkma_part_1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 24%;
     -webkit-animation: animation-hci0jy 5s 2s infinite alternate;
     animation: animation-hci0jy 5s 2s infinite alternate;
     animation-timing-function: ease;
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.43,0.05,0.6,0.99);
     animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.43,0.05,0.6,0.99);
}


.rkma_part_2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 24%;
     -webkit-animation: animation-hci0jy 5s 2s infinite alternate;
     animation: animation-hci0jy 5s 2s infinite alternate;
     animation-timing-function: ease;
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.43,0.05,0.6,0.99);
     animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.43,0.05,0.6,0.99);
}

@-webkit-keyframes animation-hci0jy{

    0% {
        -webkit-transform:translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform:translateY(0px);
        transform:translateY(0px);
        }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform:translateY(15px);
        -ms-transform:translateY(15px);
        transform:translateY(15px);
       }

   100% {
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform:translateY(0px);
    transform:translateY(0px);
   }
}

@keyframes animation-hci0jy{
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform:translateY(0px);
        transform:translateY(0px);
     }

     50% {
        -webkit-transform:translateY(15px);
        -ms-transform:translateY(15px);
        transform:translateY(15px);
     }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform:translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform:translateY(0px);
        transform:translateY(0px);
    }
}


/*---- smy-area start ----*/
.smy-area {
    background-color: #15161C;
    padding: 60px 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.smy_top h2 {
    color: #9F9F9F;
    font-size: 52px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}

.smy_top p {
    color: #9F9F9F;
    font-size: 27px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.smy_left img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.smy_left p {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 103px;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin-top: -68px;
}


.smy_right img {
    width: 180px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border: 4px solid #B9B8B8;
}

.smy_right p {
    color: #F2F2F2;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding-top: 16px;
}
/*---- tabbingsec-area start---*/
.tabbingsec-area2 {
  display: none;
}

.tabs {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tab-links:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}

.tab-links {
  padding-top: 110px
}

.tab-links li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 19px;
}

.tab-links li i {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-right: 6px;  
}

.tab-links a {
   color: #E4E4E4;
   font-size: 16px;
}

.tab-links a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tab-links li.active a {
  color: #13F1FC;
}

/*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
.tab {
  display: none;
}

.tab.active {
  display: block;
}

#tabbingsec {   
    background: #15161C;
    padding: 60px 0px;
}

.width60 {
   width: 50%;
   float: left; 
}

.width60 h3 {
    color: #9F9F9F;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.width60 p {
    color: #AAABAB;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 37px;
}

.width40 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
 }

.width40 img {
   max-width: 10%;
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
}

.width60 a {
  width: 121px;
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background:#ff8b38;
  border-radius:3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="tabbingsec">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="tabs">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-6">
                      <div class="tab-content">
                        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
                          <div class="width60">
                            <h3>First of all</h3>
                            <p>Decide where you will <br>enter into a position <br>and where you want<br> to put a stop order</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="width40"> 
                                <img src="img/ph4.png" alt=""/> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
                          <div class="width60">
                            <h3>In App</h3>
                            <p>Choose the calculator<br> depending on what<br> market you are working<br> or choose Universal</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="width40"> 
                                <img src="img/ph5.png" alt=""/> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
                          <div class="width60">
                            <h3>Balance</h3>
                            <p>Enter the amount of<br> balance or the amount<br> of money from which <br>you will count risk</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="width40"> 
                                <img src="img/ph6.png" alt=""/> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tab4" class="tab">
                          <div class="width60">
                            <h3>Required</h3>
                            <p>Enter the price at wich<br> you plan to enter into <br>position and the price <br>of the planed stop order</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="width40"> 
                                <img src="img/ph7.png" alt=""/> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tab5" class="tab">
                          <div class="width60">
                            <h3>Be WISE</h3>
                            <p>Chose the aceptable<br> risk amount in %.<br> The amount that you<br> are ready to loose in<br> case you wrong in your<br> predicrion</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="width40"> 
                                <img src="img/ph8.png" alt=""/> 
                            </div>
                         </div>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                          <ul class="tab-links">
                               <li class="active"><i class="fas fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#tab1">First step</a></li>
                               <li><i class="fas fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="#tab2">Second step</a></li>
                               <li><i class="fas fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="#tab3">Third step</a></li>
                               <li><i class="fas fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="#tab4">Fourth step</a></li>
                               <li><i class="fas fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="#tab5">Fivth step</a></li>
                          </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </section>
```

Comment: Can you share some pieces of code to try to see what's happening? It's easier to get your question answered. Check the code of conduct: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I certainly think we can help you out with your question, but it would help tremendously if you could include your HTML, CSS and potentially JS. The layout part shouldn't be too much of a trouble to make, but the interactivity with the scrolling might be a different story. Have you looked into JavaScript scrolling libraries yet?

Comment: updated the post with a code